# How to Compare two ImageIcons?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Basically, i'm using 2 images for a board game type of thing, and i change it from time to time,
So i need to be able to check if two has the same imageIcon.
For example if both uses "pirosfigura.png" from the resources folder.

```
    public String malomcheck() {
    String pirosicon=lblNewLabel.getIcon().toString();
    String pirosfilenev = pirosicon.substring(pirosicon.lastIndexOf("/"  ) + 1);
    String iconfilenev = labelhely_1.getIcon().toString();
    String filenev = iconfilenev.substring(iconfilenev.lastIndexOf("/"  ) + 1);


    if(filenev==pirosfilenev) {
        lblJtkos.setText("piros malom.");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "working");
        return "lefutott";


    }

        return "notworking. very sad.";
    }
```

By the way the return value of the getIcon().toString() is javax.swing.ImageIcon@cd7e8021
which is refers to the memory place i guess(?) so it's random with every run and for every image therefore it's seems unusable.

Comment: You're approaching this at the wrong point. The image you use to display something is just an artefact of the display. Presumably you are using some data to decide which image icon to show in each label: compare that data instead.

Comment: But also, use `.equals`, not `==`, to compare strings.

Comment: well, if i click on it, i set the label, and the "computer" sets an other label. i was like i'll just compare the images and that's it.
thanks for the .equals tip tho.

Comment: I doubt that you reliably can use `getIcon().toString()` for comparison. You need some invariant of the `Image` itself. If you load `Images` from files you can compare the file names for each Image. Alternatively you  can compare the Image data, you may need a `PixelGrabber` for that

Comment: i'm using 2 files from a source folder. it's so weird for me that there is no method to get to the filepath the Jlabel is using for an image.

Comment: Can you post the source of how you get from file name to an ImageIcon

Comment: this is the setting the image part of it.
`public void lepes(JLabel celpont,String jatekos) {
Image piros=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("pirosfigura.png")).getImage();
celpont.setIcon(new ImageIcon(piros)); 

}`

Comment: i accepted that i cannot do what i want this way, i just made an array of the same size the amount of labels i have, and each index refers to one label, if i set one it either gets a 1 or a 2 and i'll just check within the array.

Comment: Yes, I proposed a map in my answer which is conceptualy similar but a bit less fragile then indexing into an array

Comment: if this wasn't a uni project i'd do that, glad we ended up on something similar. Thanks for your time, and for the comments and answers.

Comment: @Pistee, *it's so weird for me that there is no method to get to the filepath the Jlabel is using for an image.* - makes perfect sense. A `JLabel` displays an `Icon`. You could implement the Icon interface yourself and do the custom painting for the Icon. So not all Icons will have a file path. Only an ImageIcon is created from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can achieve this, is to keep your own mapping of `ImageIcon`s to files, so that whenever you load an `ImageIcon` you store it in a `Map` as a key and its file or some symbolic name/enum as value. This way when you want to compare `imIc1` and `imIc2` you would write something like:

```
if (map.get(imIc1).equals(map.get(imIc2)) { ... }
```

or (if you have descriptive string values )

```
if (map.get(imIc1).equals("NOT_WORKING_ICON") { ... }
```

or (if you are using enum values )

```
if (map.get(imIc1) == NOT_WORKING_ICON ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's so weird for me that there is no method to get to the filepath the Jlabel is using for an image.

Makes perfect sense. A `JLabel` displays an `Icon`.

Why should a JLabel know or care about the file path?

You could implement the `Icon` interface yourself and do the custom painting for the `Icon`. So not all Icons will have a file path. Only an ImageIcon is created from a file.

The property for the file name belongs to the `ImageIcon`.

> By the way the return value of the getIcon().toString() is javax.swing.ImageIcon@cd7e8021

```
Image piros=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("pirosfigura.png")).getImage(); 
celpont.setIcon(new ImageIcon(piros));
```

Look at the above code that you are using.

You area creating an Icon from an Image, so the file information is lost.

Instead you should just create the ImageIcon directly:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( this.getClass().getResource("pirosfigura.png") ); 
celpont.setIcon( icon ); 
System.out.println( celpont.getIcon() );
```

I believe the ImageIcon will then save the filename as the "description" for the ImageIcon. It appears the toString() will return the description.